# Adding an Event listener to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to add event listener to My "Play" button but whenever I add one in either the play button disappears or I get and error.

```
package hamster.race;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HamsterRace extends JFrame {
    public HamsterRace(){
        super("HamsterRace");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(350*3, 100*5);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        setVisible(true);
        JButton Play = new JButton("Play");
        add(Play);
        add(Play);


    }
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try{
           UIManager.setLookAndFeel{
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
        };
        }catch (Exception exc) {
            //ignore error
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HamsterRace frame = new HamsterRace();


    }

}
```

Comment: `setVisible(true);` should be the last call in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

```
    JButton Play = new JButton("Play");
    add(Play);
    add(Play);
```

You only have one component. You can't add the same component twice.

So the basic code would be:

```
    //setVisible(true);
    JButton play1 = new JButton("Play1");
    add(play1);
    JButton play2 = new JButton("Play2");
    add(play2);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
```